# Spock E2E test with REST template

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spock

I cannot configure "self test" of my Spring Boot server using security. 
It means I created a self-signed certificate using [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate). When I open 
https://localhost:8080 from a browser there is no problem, I have a secure encrypted connection.

But when I want to set up a REST template to make a call to https://localhost:8080, I get this error:

```
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
```

Full stack trace:

```
Testing started at 23:45 ...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 262 ms
> Task :cleanTest
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileTestGroovy
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/pawel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.7/99907efe4b69f800c42584386f5d668e4d952bd5/groovy-2.5.7.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
23:45:30.283 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]
23:45:30.292 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]
23:45:30.299 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]
23:45:30.300 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]
23:45:30.341 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
23:45:30.355 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
23:45:30.366 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
23:45:30.401 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]: class path resource [integrationTests/IntegrationE2ETests-context.xml] does not exist
23:45:30.403 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]: class path resource [integrationTests/IntegrationE2ETestsContext.groovy] does not exist
23:45:30.404 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
23:45:30.686 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests]: using defaults.
23:45:30.686 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.spockframework.spring.SpringMockTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
23:45:30.733 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@43027667, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@70c063f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@400381eb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2afc7d1f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@7a1d9769, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1d474beb, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@41178d71, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@84a04c9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@1efa6c76, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@39457451, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@44440a0d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1cf02200, org.spockframework.spring.SpringMockTestExecutionListener@51247434]
23:45:31.156 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@12f3d1af testClass = IntegrationE2ETests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@b18bea0 testClass = IntegrationE2ETests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class pl.mazur.pawel.Family.FamilyApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{dev}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4e15caec, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2e43f120, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5af379e7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@54423ac8], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> false]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
23:45:31.178 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@12f3d1af testClass = IntegrationE2ETests, testInstance = integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests@321a3e93, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@b18bea0 testClass = IntegrationE2ETests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class pl.mazur.pawel.Family.FamilyApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{dev}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4e15caec, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2e43f120, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5af379e7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@54423ac8], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> false]]].
23:45:31.227 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}

. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot :: (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2020-01-05 23:45:32.451 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests : Starting IntegrationE2ETests on pawel-Inspiron-5558 with PID 9516 (/home/pawel/Dokumenty/Projekty/Family/build/classes/groovy/test started by pawel in /home/pawel/Dokumenty/Projekty/Family)
2020-01-05 23:45:32.452 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-01-05 23:45:34.450 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-01-05 23:45:34.610 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 134ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2020-01-05 23:45:35.437 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e917cd83] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-05 23:45:35.501 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68981ab5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-05 23:45:36.251 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (https)
2020-01-05 23:45:36.323 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-05 23:45:36.326 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2020-01-05 23:45:36.522 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-01-05 23:45:36.522 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4026 ms
2020-01-05 23:45:37.017 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-05 23:45:37.317 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-05 23:45:37.456 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2020-01-05 23:45:37.589 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] org.hibernate.Version : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-01-05 23:45:37.594 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-01-05 23:45:37.988 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-01-05 23:45:38.210 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table child if exists
Hibernate: drop table family if exists
Hibernate: drop table father if exists
Hibernate: drop table mother if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table child (id bigint not null, birth_date date not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, pesel varchar(255) not null, sex varchar(255) not null, sur_name varchar(255) not null, family_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table family (id bigint not null, father_id bigint, mother_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table father (id bigint not null, birth_date date not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, pesel varchar(255) not null, sur_name varchar(255) not null, family_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table mother (id bigint not null, birth_date date not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, pesel varchar(255) not null, sur_name varchar(255) not null, family_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table child add constraint UK_q9v1ogh011liq0u0hdp4t3q63 unique (pesel)
Hibernate: alter table father add constraint UK_iqs08tbv5crk4816q89odbm4g unique (pesel)
Hibernate: alter table mother add constraint UK_88axw5moqy5wi4636k36l31m3 unique (pesel)
Hibernate: alter table child add constraint FKhj2xmiglh5fr64tvotyhjb61p foreign key (family_id) references family
Hibernate: alter table family add constraint FKp8unxl9i7iewr8wronod7arjc foreign key (father_id) references father
Hibernate: alter table family add constraint FKbxs2svee13oxyxx1bx8gdhy7g foreign key (mother_id) references mother
Hibernate: alter table father add constraint FK9wsh8dwpsy38hpdxkly22pu96 foreign key (family_id) references family
Hibernate: alter table mother add constraint FK4ebc98bboc1csv95bt6qklsso foreign key (family_id) references family
2020-01-05 23:45:39.630 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@64c0b2e1'
2020-01-05 23:45:39.634 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-05 23:45:40.404 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2020-01-05 23:45:41.376 WARN 9516 --- [ Test worker] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-01-05 23:45:42.055 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2020-01-05 23:45:42.388 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-05 23:45:42.897 WARN 9516 --- [ Test worker] .b.a.g.t.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Groovy configuration, or set spring.groovy.template.check-template-location=false)
2020-01-05 23:45:43.557 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-01-05 23:45:43.583 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-01-05 23:45:43.622 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner : Scanning for api listing references
2020-01-05 23:45:45.269 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 41435 (https) with context path ''
2020-01-05 23:45:45.275 INFO 9516 --- [ Test worker] integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests : Started IntegrationE2ETests in 14.043 seconds (JVM running for 16.095)

I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:41435/family/create": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:41435/family/create": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:338)
at integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests.adding flow (IntegrationE2ETests.groovy:39)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1324)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1199)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1146)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1308)
... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 26 more

2020-01-05 23:45:45.916 INFO 9516 --- [ Thread-6] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-05 23:45:45.924 INFO 9516 --- [ Thread-6] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-05 23:45:45.925 INFO 9516 --- [ Thread-6] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: drop table child if exists
integrationTests.IntegrationE2ETests > adding flow FAILED
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException at IntegrationE2ETests.groovy:39
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException at IntegrationE2ETests.groovy:39
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException at IntegrationE2ETests.groovy:39
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException at IntegrationE2ETests.groovy:39
Hibernate: drop table family if exists
Hibernate: drop table father if exists
Hibernate: drop table mother if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
2020-01-05 23:45:45.988 INFO 9516 --- [ Thread-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-05 23:45:46.006 INFO 9516 --- [ Thread-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/pawel/Dokumenty/Projekty/Family/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 33s
6 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I searched the whole internet found articles how to load x.509 certificate from disk and then use to "self-call" but I would like it to push this to work like browser.

Test class and project:
https://github.com/mpawel1993/Family/blob/master/src/test/groovy/integrationTests/IntegrationE2ETests.groovy

Comment: Are these tests running inside your application JVM with `@SpringBootTest` or run externally by some CI or similar system?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give your question a bit more love next time and use a spelling checker. Please also paste your code or stack trace info inline rather than linking to external websites. It would also be advisable to learn about formatting options on SO such as code formatting vs. quoted text. Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This test running inside JVM. At the beginning I used MockMvc but I read the MockMvc is not working on HTTP that's why I want to use RestTemplete. RestTemplete (Autowired) will make REST call to my server and its most close to real user call to application. At the root, I want to "change" my browser to RestTemplete with SSL/HTTPS connection but I cannot configure this because of SSLHandshakeException

Comment: This should be added to your Question, the "Your Answer" is not for replying to comments. Either edit your question or use the "add a comment" link.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just disable SSL for tests, as it unnecessarily increases the complexity, as you've seen. I'd suggest adding a `test` profile and activate it via `@ActiveProfiles(['dev', 'test'])`.

As for the `test` profile simply set `server.ssl.enabled=false`.

If you really need to use SSL for your tests, then I'd suggest you follow the tutorial here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

Also after looking at your code I'd suggest to look at [data driven testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_data_driven_testing) with spock.